# LIMIT with ORDER BY slowdown query solution for geospacial mysql 5.7

Tags: mysql, performance, sql-order-by, geospatial, mysql-5.7

On a geospacial search with a geospacial index on geom field , my time query increase anormaly when i want to ORDER BY distance , is there an alternative syntax ou tricks to avoid that ? 
Note i'm aware about this post: https://explainextended.com/2011/02/11/late-row-lookups-innodb/
but this trick cannot be achieve with the query bellow :

**this query without order by take 0.005s**

```
SELECT 
ST_Distance_Sphere(Point(2.34, 48.85), geom)  as distance
FROM testgeo1
WHERE ST_Contains( ST_MakeEnvelope(
                    Point((2.34+(500/111)), (48.85+(500/111))),
                    Point((2.34-(500/111)), (48.85-(500/111)))
                 ), geom ) 
   LIMIT 500
```

EXPLAIN :

```
+----+-------------+----------+------------+-------+---------------+----------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table    | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key      | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+----------+------------+-------+---------------+----------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | testgeo1 | NULL       | range | sp_index      | sp_index | 34      | NULL | 2609 |   100.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+----------+------------+-------+---------------+----------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
```

**this one with ORDER BY takes 0.16s**

```
    SELECT 
    ST_Distance_Sphere(Point(2.34, 48.85), geom)  as distance
    FROM testgeo1
    WHERE ST_Contains( ST_MakeEnvelope(
                        Point((2.34+(500/111)), (48.85+(500/111))),
                        Point((2.34-(500/111)), (48.85-(500/111)))
                     ), geom ) 
ORDER BY distance
       LIMIT 500
```

solutions , suggestion , alternative syntax or tricks are welcome ..

Comment: @Rick ur link goes to localhost .. can you fix it please

Comment: (Sorry...)  The design in  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/latlng  may be faster.

Comment: @Rick ur metheod seems interesting but i would keep the newest Mysql standard method as i posted , this way is very efficient wihout order by , its just pointing on a common mysql bug , i'm searching for a simple alternative syntax/trick , see this note : https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/improvements-to-order-by/    thanks anayway

Comment: BTW, the 1-million sq. km. bounding rectangle need a `cos` multiplier so to avoid unnecessarily extending the longitudes when at high latitudes, such as Paris.

Answer (score 0):

If there are many thousands of points within that envelope,...

- The first query (no `ORDER BY`) will pick the first 500 it finds in that envelope.
- The second query (with `ORDER BY`) must find all points in the envelope, compute the distance for each one, sort the result, then deliver 500.

This is a simple fact-of-life about `LIMIT` with and without `ORDER BY`.  It has nothing specific to do with `SPATIAL` or 5.7.

Please provide evidence for what I am claiming by doing

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM testgeo1
    WHERE ST_Contains( ST_MakeEnvelope(
                Point((2.34+(500/111)), (48.85+(500/111))),
                Point((2.34-(500/111)), (48.85-(500/111)))
             ), geom ) ;
```

Comment: the outputt is 1277  , i have 1 million rows in the table , not sure to see whats the point ..

Comment: It had to compute `ST_Distance_Sphere` 1277 times.  Alas, that is not enough to make my point.  Please post `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`

Comment: i edited my post and added the explain query , i wonder if its a  "common order by bug" with mysql , i'd like to test the same on mariadb but im not sure thoses mysql 5.7 function are implemented yet

Comment: That the distance function was added in 5.7.6; I doubt if MariaDB has it.